# Arraylist<String> ArrayAdaptor to display 2 Arraylist<String> in one ListView

Tags: android, listview, arraylist, android-arrayadapter

I have two `ArrayList<String>`'s, and I want to display them side-by-side in order, inside one `ListView`.

I have setup a custom "`row`", `ListView`, and understand how to `list.setAdapter(myAdapter)`.

My issue is `myAdaptor` doesn't work.

How can I fix this `ArrayAdaptor` to work display two `ArrayList<String>`?

**CustomArrayAdaptor.java**

```
public class CustomArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Words> {
    private ArrayList<Words> arrayOne;
    private ArrayList<Words> arrayTwo;

    public CustomArrayAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<Words> arrayOne, ArrayList<Words> arrayTwo) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, arrayOne, arrayTwo);
        this.arrayOne = arrayOne;
        this.generates = arrayTwo;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
        View v = convertView;
        if (v == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
        }

        Words a = arrayOne.get(position);
        Words g = arrayTwo.get(position);

        if (a != null) {
            TextView arrayOne = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.text_view_1);
            TextView arrayTwo = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.text_view_2);
        }

        return v;
    }
}
```

Comment: You're never actually setting the text on your TextViews arrayOne and arrayTwo in your Adapter's getView method, which explains why you're not seeing anything. Also, there's no need to have 2 ArrayList<Word> in your Adapter since your Word object holds a reference to Strings from both your ArrayList<String> (I'm assuming).

Comment: Ok, I'll remove the `ArrayList<Word>` and setText to "" + arrayOne.size() and see if that works

Comment: See my answer below for more info http://stackoverflow.com/a/24812054/1426565

Comment: Cut paste these 2 lines inside if(v == null)     TextView arrayOne = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.text_view_1);
    TextView arrayTwo = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.text_view_2);

Answer (score 0):

From my comment:

You're never actually setting the text on your TextViews arrayOne and arrayTwo in your Adapter's getView method, which explains why you're not seeing anything. Also, there's no need to have 2 ArrayList in your Adapter since your Word object holds a reference to Strings from both your ArrayList (I'm assuming)

Here's an adjusted Adapter meeting my original suggestions:

```
public class CustomArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Words> {

    private ArrayList<Words> arrayOne;

    public CustomArrayAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<Words> arrayOne) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, arrayOne);
        this.arrayOne = arrayOne;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
        }

        Words a = arrayOne.get(position);
        if (a != null) {
            TextView text1 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text_view_1);
            text1.setText(a.getWordOne());

            TextView text2 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text_view_2);
            text2.setText(a.getWordTwo());
        }

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

I would also suggest looking at the [View Holder Pattern](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html) for efficiency so you're not always calling findViewById() on every layout pass.

Answer (score 0):

First thing is paste these below 2 lines inside "if block" of (v == null)

```
    TextView arrayOne = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.text_view_1);
    TextView arrayTwo = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.text_view_2);
```

And

Actually you have not set values to your textview yet. So you need to set values to those textviews.

See below:

```
    arrayOne.setText("" + arrayOne.get(position));
    arrayTwo.setText("" + arrayTwo.get(position));
```

Just copy paste these 2 lines in your getView method. Your problem will be solved.